# Consulta a Variable EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq

Quiero traer solo algunos campos de lo que me trae la consulta,

```
 var result = dbContext.Cliente.Include("Contacto.Cliente").ToList();
```

esto me trae lo siguiente :

```
 "Objects": [
{
  "IdCliente": 3,
  "Identificacion": 10,
  "Nombre": "Ebony Kemp",
  "Direccion": "855-3865 Ipsum Street",
  "Telefono": "1626010138799",
  "Estado": true,
  "FechaCreacion": "2012-06-18T10:34:09",
  "FechaModificacion": "2012-06-18T10:34:09",
  "UsuarioCreacion": "7a4f4875-0c70-fa98-b29b-331ff027fd67",
  "UsuarioModificacion": "44a1e2b1-2be6-fad2-84e1-6eb3cec55cc0",
  "Contacto": [
    {
      "IdContacto": 2,
      "Nombres": "juan",
      "Apellidos": "hincapie",
      "Direccion": null,
      "Telefono": "555555",
      "Email": null,
      "Estado": true,
      "IdCliente": 3,
      "IdTipoContacto": 1,
      "FechaCreacion": null,
      "FechaModificacion": null,
      "UsuarioCreacion": null,
      "UsuarioModificacion": null
    }
  ]
},
```

Pero quiero que solo me retorne :

```
"Objects": [{
    "Identificacion": 10,
    "Nombre": "Ebony Kemp",
    "Contacto":  "juan"
}]
```

Pero solo los que esten en estado **true** y que tengan el **IdTipoContacto** **: 1** (El idTipoContacto esta relacionado con una tabla TipoContacto),

**Adicionalmente, tendría que devolver una lista de tipo Cliente(no una anónima)**

Podrían Ayudarme en como traer solo esos datos con la mejor practica posible? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto vas a tener que realizar un linq mas concreto

```
var result = from c in dbContext.Cliente
             select new {
                Identificacion = c.Identificacion,
                Nombre =c.Nombre,
                Contacto = c.Contacto.Where(x=> x.Estado && x.IdTipoContacto == 1)
                                        .Select(x=> x.Nombres )
            };
```

en este caso solo defiens los campos que necesitas y filtras los contactos asociados al cliente. Se supone que entre el cliente y sus contactos hay una relacion que permite navegar la asociacion.

Sino quieres devolver un objeto anonimo vas a tener que crea una clase como ser:

```
public class ClienteDto{
   public int Identificacion {get;set;}
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
   public string Contacto {get;set;}
}
```

entonces el linq seria

```
var result = from c in dbContext.Cliente
             select new ClienteDto() {
                Identificacion = c.Identificacion,
                Nombre =c.Nombre,
                Contacto = c.Contacto.Where(x=> x.Estado && x.IdTipoContacto == 1)
                                        .Select(x=> x.Nombres )
            };
```

Comment: Leandro, Entiendo tu respuesta y funciona a la perfección, pero lo ideal es no devolver una lista anónima, si no una lista de Cliente, puedes ayudarme en ese punto porfavor?

Comment: pero si serializas a json no afecta que sea una lista anonima. Sino vas a tener que crear una clase para aplanar los datos

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando la alternativa que no devuelve un objeto anonimo

Comment: Si de echo tengo una clase, por eso debo de retornar una clase en este caso seria la clase cliente, pero ya con estos datos de la consulta, puedes  darme una referencia de como puedo aplanar los datos en esa clase?

Answer (score 0):

Realizando una consulta con LINQ puedes resolver el problema:

```
var elementos= from cliente in dbContext.Cliente
               Join contacto in dbContext.Contacto on contacto.IdCliente equals cliente.IdCliente
               Where contacto.Estado==true && contacto. IdTipoContacto == 1
Seletc new
{
identificacion=cliente.Identificacion
clienteNombre=cliente.Nombre
contactoNombre=contacto.Nombre
};
return elementos.toList();
```

Esto te devuelve una lista de objectos anonimos con los campos
-identificacion,-clienteNombre,-contactosNombre....

Comment: que sucede si tienes un cliente que tiene un solo contacto en false ? si defines el where a ese nivel el cliente nunca apareceria como respuesta. Entiendo que la idea es que se muestren todos los cliente tengan o no contactos, pero si lo tienen que mueste solo los estado=true y tipo contracto = 1

Comment: Exacto @LeandroTuttini eso es lo que quiero lograr!

Comment: habia entendido todos los clientes con contactos que cumplieran esa condicion....

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que tu deseas podrías crear una clase donde te presentara los datos que tu deseas:
Por ejemplo:

```
 class ClientePresenter
    {
public ClientePresenter(){}
    public int Id{get;set;}//esto para tener referencia de que registro es..
    public int Identificacion{get;set;}
    public string clienteNombre{get;set;}
    public string contactoNombre{get;set;}

    }
```

y despues realizar:

```
var result = from c in dbContext.Cliente
             select new ClientePresenter{
                Id=c.Id
                Identificacion = c.Identificacion,
                clienteNombre =c.Nombre,
                contactoNombre = c.Contacto.Where(x=> x.Estado && x.IdTipoContacto == 1)
                                        .Select(x=> x.Nombres )
            };
```

Comment: @Kmiilo si devuelves con linq un objeto de tipo cliente al final vas a tener acceso a todos los atributos de esa clase y no responde a lo que preguntas solo tener algunos campos

Comment: si entiendo, pero lo que pasa es que obligatoria mente tendría que devolver un objeto de tipo cliente ya que después lo estoy mapeando a otra clase, y solo para la consulta necesito eso, osea que necesitaría en este caso setiar los datos de esa consulta a mi entidad como tal, para poderlo retornar pero no encuentro la forma, se que como dices que voy a tener acceso a todo pero en este caso seria diferente porque solo voy a mostrar algunos datos, osea que los otros parametos estarian vacios

Comment: @Kmiilo por lo que entendi quieres devolver el objeto de tipo Cliente, si es asi pon en new Cliente en la consulta y llena solos los datos que quieras...

Comment: Si eso quiero pero me sale una excepción Mira **no se puede construir el tipo de entidad o complejo en una consulta linq to entities**

Comment: tu entidad cliente tiene constructor??

Comment: No amigo no tiene,